# Оптимальный формат изображений на сайте

Tags: frontend, изображения, pagespeed-insights

Появилась острая необходимость в оптимизации изображений на сайте. Как увеличить скорость загрузки сайта путем уменьшение объема загружаемых изображений? Для тестирования результата использую несколько разных способов:

1. Тестирование инструментом [PageSpeed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?hl=ru)
2. Измерение общего объема сайта до и после оптимизации изображений.

Знаю 4 основных формата изображений используемых в Web:

1. JPEG
2. GIF
3. PNG
4. SVG

В основном использую именно JPEG и PNG. Поэтому занимался оптимизацией именно их. Этого вроде бы хватало. Но совсем недавно PageSpeed Insights изменился кардинально, например данное обновление описано на [Хабре](https://habr.com/post/429668/). Ранее были рекомендации по сжатию изображений, сейчас же Google рекомендует использовать современные форматы изображений JPEG 2000, JPEG XR и WebP.

> Используйте современные форматы изображений
>
> Для изображений в форматах JPEG 2000, JPEG XR и WebP используется
> более эффективное сжатие, поэтому они загружаются быстрее и потребляют
> меньше трафика, чем изображения PNG и JPEG.

[image: современные форматы изображений JPEG 2000, JPEG XR и WebP]
От предлагаемых форматов изображений я просто в шоке.

---

Главные проблемы, которые меня беспокоят:

1. Поддержка браузерами
2. Размер изображений

Разберёмся со всеми пунктами по порядку.

**Пункт №1**

Для анализа поддержки браузерами буду использовать сервис [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/).

Результат формата изображений JPEG - не дал результатов

Результат формата изображений PNG
[image: Результат формата изображений PNG]

Результат формата изображений JPEG 2000
[image: Результат формата изображений JPEG 2000]
Результат формата изображений JPEG XR
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Результат формата изображений WebP
[image: Результат формата изображений WebP]
Результат просто ошеломительный. В моём понимании, я теперь должен использовать эти современные форматы изображений, загружая в зависимости от браузера разную по формате картинку пользователю? Или на примере интернет магазина, это как вообще?

**Пункт №2**
В этом пункте использовав одно изображение в JPEG, я переконвертировал его в разные форматы.

Изображение в формате JPEG

Размер 1,26 МБ
Ссылка https://ibb.co/bxGFh0
[image: Изображение в формате JPEG]

Изображение в формате PNG

Размер 6,97 МБ

Ссылка https://ibb.co/etc7Uf

Изображение в формате JPEG 2000

Размер 2,71 МБ

Изображение в формате JPEG XR

Размер 10,4 МБ

Изображение в формате WebP

Размер 704 КБ

---

### Использовать JPEG, GIF, PNG, SVG или JPEG 2000, JPEG XR, WebP? Как?

Comment: Вариант игнорировать результаты PageSpeed Insights в принципе не рассматривается? Вариант по возможности избавиться от изображений совсем тоже не рассматривается?

Comment: Вообще, если вам необходимо помещать на сайт картинку ТАКОГО размера, то скорее всего что-то не так с самой сутью сайта

Comment: @andreymal нет, отказаться на сайте нет возможности. я беру в пример интернет магазины. Такого размера взял изображение без оптимизации, для примера. Мог бы взять меньше, поменялось бы в другую сторону?

Comment: Если это большой список товаров с картинками, то можно просто ленивую подгрузку изображений на js сделать

Comment: Для фотографий - делать жипег с качеством 80-90% (выбрать по вкусу). Для клипартов и т.п. (где мало градиентов) можно использовать png или gif.

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать в Adobe Photoshop встроенный оптимизатор "для Web", при сохранении изображения.
Возможна гибкая настройка по соотношению качество-вес/скорость

Comment: как использовать Ваш совет в условиях массовой оптимизации изображений?

Comment: Если массово, тогда FastStone Image Viewer.
Есть хорошая статья по уменьшению веса картинок без потерь:
https://goldbusinessnet.com/seo-programmy-i-servisy/programma-dlya-prosmotra-izobrazhenij-faststone-image-viewer-kak-umenshit-razmer-foto/